# Script declared in rc.local doesn't run after soft reboot

Tags: bash

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and two scripts that handle the updates of an app.

1. download.sh
2. update.sh

download.sh downloads the new version of the app, prepares it for deployment and restarts the device.
update.sh is declared in the rc.local file and runs perfectly when I do a hard reset. But nothing happens when the device is rebooted from the download.sh with the following command `shutdown -r now`

Comment: Without the scripts who can tell. But it is unlikely you can do this in rc.local.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference between the reboot modes. You are just lucky. Any difference is likely to be external to the Pi.

DO NOT use `rc.local` (as advised in the hundreds of similar questions on this site).
It runs BEFORE all services are running.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md